# Insufficient memory error in proc sort

Tags: oracle, sorting, sas, out-of-memory

My data is stored in Oracle table MY_DATA. This table contains only 2 rows with 7 columns. But when I execute step:

```
proc sort data=oraclelib.MY_DATA nodupkey out=SORTED_DATA;
by client_number;
run;
```

the following error appears:

```
 ERROR: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient memory.
```

If I comment `nodupkey` option then error disappears. If I copy dataset in work library and execute proc sort on it then everything is OK too.

My memory options:

```
SORTSIZE=1073741824
SUMSIZE=0
MAXMEMQUERY=268435456
LOADMEMSIZE=0    
MEMSIZE=31565617920
REALMEMSIZE=0
```

What can be the root of the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: That sounds like a question you should ask SAS support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Oracle password was in grace period and when I changed it the issue disappeared.